# How to define a global variable in nginx conf file

Tags: nginx

How to define a global variable in nginx conf file, define a global var in http block,and all servers and locations below can use it.

```
http{
      some confs
      ...
      //define a global var mabe like
      set APP_ROOT /home/admin
      // and it can be use in all servers and locations below, like
      server {
        root $APP_ROOT/test1
      }

      server {
        root $APP_ROOT/test2
      }
  }
```

Comment: Anything set in server { } block is inherited.

Comment: You mean if I define a var in the first server, then I can use it in all server blocks below it?

Comment: I KNOW this is 8 years old.   I don't know if that worked back then, but it doesn't work today.
---
set directive is used in server, location and if blocks.   Not allowed in http context block.

Syntax: set $variable value;
Default: —
Context: server, location, if

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#set

Answer (score 114):

You can do a little trick. If this value must be accessible from every `server` block in one `http` block you can use `map` directive. How will this work?

The `map` directive allows you to use a variable anywhere in an `http` block which value will be calculated on some map key. All-telling example:

```
http {

  ...

  /* 
     value for your $my_everywhere_used_variable will be calculated
     each time when you use it and it will be based on the value of $query_string.
  */
  map $query_string $my_everywhere_used_variable {

    /* 
       if the actual value of $query_string exactly match this below then 
       $my_everywhere_used_variable will have a value of 3
    */
    /x=1&y=2&opr=plus     3;

    /* 
       if the actual value of $query_string exactly match this below then
       $my_everywhere_used_variable will have a value of 4
    */
    /x=1&y=4&opr=multi    4;

  /*
    it needs to be said that $my_everywhere_used_variable's value is calculated each
    time you use it. When you use it as pattern in a map directive (here we used the
    $query_string variable) some variable which will occasionally change 
    (for example $args) you can get more flexible values based on specific conditions
  */
  }

  // now in server you can use this variable as you want, for example:

  server {

    location / {
      rewrite .* /location_number/$my_everywhere_used_variable;
      /* 
         the value to set here as $my_everywhere_used_variable will be
         calculated from the map directive based on $query_string value
      */
    }
  }
}
```

So now, what does this mean for you? You can use the `map` directive to set a global variable for all `server` blocks with this simple trick. You can use the `default` keyword to set a default value for your *map value*. As in this simple example:

```
map $host $my_variable {
  default lalalala;
}
```

In this example we calculate the value of `$my_variable` on the `$host` value, but in fact it doesn't matter what `$host` is because we will always set *lalalala* as the value for our variable by default and without other options. Now everywhere in your code when you will use `$my_variable` in the same way as all other available variables (for example created with `set` directive) you will get value of *lalalala*

And why is this better than simply using the `set` directive? Because the `set` directive, as doc says [nginx set directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#set) is only accessible inside `server, location and if` blocks, so it cannot be used to create global variable for a number of `server` blocks.

Docs about `map` directive are available here: [map directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map)

Comment: nice!
Can I overwrite global variable using map directive?

Comment: Any Idea how to access $my_everywhere_used_variable in Lua block?

Comment: just use `ngx.var.my_everywhere_used_variable` in lua

Comment: BTW: `set` directive can be used inside `http.server` but not inside `stream.server`.

Comment: This only work when using the variable to handle a connection inside a server{} block. It's not a real global variable in the sense you will not able to use it anywhere in your server configuration, for example like this: `  map $host $host_ip {
    default 1.2.3.4;
  }
server {
  listen       $host_ip:80;
...
}`
This will give an error like this:
nginx: [emerg] host not found in "$host_ip:80" of the "listen" directive