# SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream nginx-proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, jwilder-nginx-proxy

- I am trying to setup my docker compose node.js express application that uses redis postgres and nginx-proxy to manage certificates
- I am using the test or staging version of letsencrypt currently on my subdomains and

It keeps giving me this error

```
nginx-proxy           | 2023/05/12 08:21:53 [error] 39#39: *8 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 183.87.21.243, server: www.api.coinhexa.com, request: "GET /admin HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://172.18.0.7:21347/admin", host: "www.api.coinhexa.com"
nginx-proxy           | www.api.coinhexa.com 183.87.21.243 - - [12/May/2023:08:21:53 +0000] "GET /admin HTTP/2.0" 502 157 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0" "172.18.0.7:21347"
nginx-proxy           | 2023/05/12 08:21:54 [error] 39#39: *8 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 183.87.21.243, server: www.api.coinhexa.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://172.18.0.7:21347/favicon.ico", host: "www.api.coinhexa.com", referrer: "https://www.api.coinhexa.com/admin"
nginx-proxy           | www.api.coinhexa.com 183.87.21.243 - - [12/May/2023:08:21:54 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0" 502 157 "https://www.api.coinhexa.com/admin" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0" "172.18.0.7:21347"
```

[image]

Visually I see this bad gateway error. I double checked my IP address on EC2 and the domain provider to see if everything is pointed in the right direction and it seems fine.

[image]

Just to verify that is not an issue with my node.js app, I tried the IP directly and it works just fine without SSL

I ran nginx -T inside my docker container to get the loaded nginx configuration

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                                        html htm shtml;
    text/css                                         css;
    text/xml                                         xml;
    image/gif                                        gif;
    image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                           js;
    application/atom+xml                             atom;
    application/rss+xml                              rss;

    text/mathml                                      mml;
    text/plain                                       txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor                 jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                                 wml;
    text/x-component                                 htc;

    image/avif                                       avif;
    image/png                                        png;
    image/svg+xml                                    svg svgz;
    image/tiff                                       tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                               wbmp;
    image/webp                                       webp;
    image/x-icon                                     ico;
    image/x-jng                                      jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                                   bmp;

    font/woff                                        woff;
    font/woff2                                       woff2;

    application/java-archive                         jar war ear;
    application/json                                 json;
    application/mac-binhex40                         hqx;
    application/msword                               doc;
    application/pdf                                  pdf;
    application/postscript                           ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                                  rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl                    m3u8;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml             kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz                 kmz;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                         xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject                    eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                    ppt;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics      odg;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation  odp;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet   ods;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text          odt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                                                     pptx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                                                     xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                                                     docx;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc                         wmlc;
    application/wasm                                 wasm;
    application/x-7z-compressed                      7z;
    application/x-cocoa                              cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff                  jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file                     jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                           run;
    application/x-perl                               pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                              prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed                     rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager             rpm;
    application/x-sea                                sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash                    swf;
    application/x-stuffit                            sit;
    application/x-tcl                                tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert                       der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall                          xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                            xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                             xspf;
    application/zip                                  zip;

    application/octet-stream                         bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream                         deb;
    application/octet-stream                         dmg;
    application/octet-stream                         iso img;
    application/octet-stream                         msi msp msm;

    audio/midi                                       mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                                       mp3;
    audio/ogg                                        ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                                      m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                                ra;

    video/3gpp                                       3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                                       ts;
    video/mp4                                        mp4;
    video/mpeg                                       mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                                  mov;
    video/webm                                       webm;
    video/x-flv                                      flv;
    video/x-m4v                                      m4v;
    video/x-mng                                      mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                                   asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                                   wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                                  avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:
# nginx-proxy
# Networks available to the container running docker-gen (which are assumed to
# match the networks available to the container running nginx):
#     coinhexa_prod_network
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Proto, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# scheme used to connect to this server
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto {
    default $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    '' $scheme;
}
map $http_x_forwarded_host $proxy_x_forwarded_host {
    default $http_x_forwarded_host;
    '' $http_host;
}
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Port, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# server port the client connected to
map $http_x_forwarded_port $proxy_x_forwarded_port {
    default $http_x_forwarded_port;
    '' $server_port;
}
# If the request from the downstream client has an "Upgrade:" header (set to any
# non-empty value), pass "Connection: upgrade" to the upstream (backend) server.
# Otherwise, the value for the "Connection" header depends on whether the user
# has enabled keepalive to the upstream server.
map $http_upgrade $proxy_connection {
    default upgrade;
    '' $proxy_connection_noupgrade;
}
map $upstream_keepalive $proxy_connection_noupgrade {
    # Preserve nginx's default behavior (send "Connection: close").
    default close;
    # Use an empty string to cancel nginx's default behavior.
    true '';
}
# Abuse the map directive (see <https://stackoverflow.com/q/14433309>) to ensure
# that $upstream_keepalive is always defined.  This is necessary because:
#   - The $proxy_connection variable is indirectly derived from
#     $upstream_keepalive, so $upstream_keepalive must be defined whenever
#     $proxy_connection is resolved.
#   - The $proxy_connection variable is used in a proxy_set_header directive in
#     the http block, so it is always fully resolved for every request -- even
#     those where proxy_pass is not used (e.g., unknown virtual host).
map "" $upstream_keepalive {
    # The value here should not matter because it should always be overridden in
    # a location block (see the "location" template) for all requests where the
    # value actually matters.
    default false;
}
# Apply fix for very long server names
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
# Default dhparam
# Set appropriate X-Forwarded-Ssl header based on $proxy_x_forwarded_proto
map $proxy_x_forwarded_proto $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl {
    default off;
    https on;
}
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
log_format vhost '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$upstream_addr"';
access_log off;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
error_log /dev/stderr;
# HTTP 1.1 support
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $proxy_x_forwarded_host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $proxy_x_forwarded_port;
proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
# Mitigate httpoxy attack (see README for details)
proxy_set_header Proxy "";
server {
    server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
    server_tokens off;
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/default.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/default.key;
    return 503;
}
# api.coinhexa.com/
upstream api.coinhexa.com {
    # Container: api_server_prod
    #     networks:
    #         coinhexa_prod_network (reachable)
    #     IP address: 172.18.0.7
    #     exposed ports: 21347/tcp
    #     default port: 21347
    #     using port: 21347
    #         /!\ WARNING: Virtual port published on host.  Clients
    #                      might be able to bypass nginx-proxy and
    #                      access the container's server directly.
    server 172.18.0.7:21347;
}
server {
    server_name api.coinhexa.com;
    listen 80 ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    # Do not HTTPS redirect Let's Encrypt ACME challenge
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        auth_basic off;
        auth_request off;
        allow all;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri =404;
        break;
    }
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    server_name api.coinhexa.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    listen 443 ssl http2 ;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/api.coinhexa.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/api.coinhexa.com.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/api.coinhexa.com.dhparam.pem;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/api.coinhexa.com.chain.pem;
    set $sts_header "";
    if ($https) {
        set $sts_header "max-age=31536000";
    }
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security $sts_header always;
    include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://api.coinhexa.com;
        set $upstream_keepalive false;
    }
}
# www.api.coinhexa.com/
upstream www.api.coinhexa.com {
    # Container: api_server_prod
    #     networks:
    #         coinhexa_prod_network (reachable)
    #     IP address: 172.18.0.7
    #     exposed ports: 21347/tcp
    #     default port: 21347
    #     using port: 21347
    #         /!\ WARNING: Virtual port published on host.  Clients
    #                      might be able to bypass nginx-proxy and
    #                      access the container's server directly.
    server 172.18.0.7:21347;
}
server {
    server_name www.api.coinhexa.com;
    listen 80 ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    # Do not HTTPS redirect Let's Encrypt ACME challenge
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        auth_basic off;
        auth_request off;
        allow all;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri =404;
        break;
    }
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    server_name www.api.coinhexa.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    listen 443 ssl http2 ;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/www.api.coinhexa.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/www.api.coinhexa.com.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/www.api.coinhexa.com.dhparam.pem;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/www.api.coinhexa.com.chain.pem;
    set $sts_header "";
    if ($https) {
        set $sts_header "max-age=31536000";
    }
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security $sts_header always;
    include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://www.api.coinhexa.com;
        set $upstream_keepalive false;
    }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default:
## Start of configuration add by letsencrypt container
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    auth_basic off;
    auth_request off;
    allow all;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri =404;
    break;
}
## End of configuration add by letsencrypt container
```

Here is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.9' # optional since v1.27.0
name: coinhexa_api_prod
services:
  api_server_prod:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: ./docker/production/api_server/Dockerfile
    container_name: api_server_prod
    depends_on:
      cache_server_prod:
        condition: service_healthy
      database_server_prod:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - ACME_OCSP=true
      - DEBUG=1
      - DEFAULT_EMAIL=something@gmail.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=something@gmail.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=api.coinhexa.com,www.api.coinhexa.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_TEST=true
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=api.coinhexa.com,www.api.coinhexa.com
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=21347
      - VIRTUAL_PROTO=https
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: api_server_prod_image
    networks:
      - network
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - '21347:21347'

  cache_server_prod:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/production/cache_server/Dockerfile
    container_name: cache_server_prod
    env_file:
      - .env
    healthcheck:
      test:
        ['CMD-SHELL', 'redis-cli -p 23431 -a $REDIS_PASSWORD ping | grep PONG']
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s
    image: cache_server_prod_image
    networks:
      - network
    ports:
      - '23431:23431'
    restart: 'always'
    volumes:
      - cache_volume:/data

  database_server_prod:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/production/database_server/Dockerfile
    container_name: database_server_prod
    env_file:
      - .env
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          'CMD-SHELL',
          "pg_isready -d 'host=database_server_prod user=coinhexa_api_user port=26189 dbname=coinhexa_api_db'",
        ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s
    image: database_server_prod_image
    networks:
      - network
    ports:
      - '26189:26189'
    restart: 'always'
    volumes:
      - database_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
    networks:
      - network

  docker-gen:
    image: jwilder/docker-gen
    container_name: nginx-proxy-gen
    command: -notify-sighup nginx-proxy -watch /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-proxy
    volumes:
      - /home/ec2-user/api/docker/production/web_server/nginx.tmpl:/etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    labels:
      - 'com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.docker_gen'
    networks:
      - network

  acme-companion:
    image: nginxproxy/acme-companion
    container_name: nginx-proxy-acme
    depends_on:
      - docker-gen
      - nginx-proxy
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-proxy
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - acme:/etc/acme.sh
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - network

networks:
  network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  cache_volume:
    driver: local
  database_volume:
    driver: local
  conf:
    driver: local
  vhost:
    driver: local
  html:
    driver: local
  certs:
    driver: local
  acme:
    driver: local
```

Can someone kindly tell me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely caused by this block :

```
location / {
  proxy_pass https://www.api.coinhexa.com;
  set $upstream_keepalive false;
}
```

And your `upstream` (`server 172.18.0.7:21347`) being an HTTP endpoint.

Change your `proxy_pass` directive to use HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Not related, but using the same names (`www.api.coinhexa.com`) on both `upstream`s and `server_name`s makes the configuration a bit confusing and possibly cause issues.

Comment: i ll have to test this but this configuration seems to be auto generated by nginx-proxy https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy

Comment: Thanks for the link. [According to the readme, it should be http](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy/blob/main/README.md?plain=1#L582-L584).

Comment: Have you got around to test it @PirateApp ?

Comment: yep that worked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!@gileri thank you very much, my api_server was definitely not running https, you are correct